# Dashcode and Adobe Air

Tags: air, dashcode

Can Dashcode be used to compile and run Adobe Air projects? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Dashcode is an IDE for creating Mac Widgets and Webkit based Web Apps. It uses, or a project consists of, HTML, JavaScript and CSS. It also provides a library of parts and "widgets" and prewritten code to shorten the development process and Mac Widgets can interact with the underlying Mac at run time.

When you use it to deploy a project it is not in any way compiling anything but packaging the build elements for deployment.